# multiple command in process builder

Tags: java

How can I give multiple command in process builder.
Basically my first command is to enter in nusmv interface then further commands are nusmv commands to create xml file but my program is not working after first command, it is not taking further commands.

```
String[][] commands =  {
        {"nusmv", "-int", "D:/files/bitshift.smv"},
        {"go"},
        {"process_model"},
        {"show_traces","-p","4","-o","D:output.xml"}};


for (String[] str : commands) {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(str);
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

            Process process = pb.start();

            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String inputLine;
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        System.err.println("next one");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to brush up your understanding of the process model, and read the ProcessBuilder documentation in light of that.

What your code does is, create a process to run the command "nusmv -int D:/files/bitshift.smv", then create a *new* process to (try to) run the command "go", and so on. Clearly that is not what you want.

You want one process; you want it to run "nusmv", and you want to write commands to its input. Assuming that "nusmv" reads commands from stdin in a conventional way, you should be able to do something like:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("numv","-int","D:/files/bitshift.smv");
Process process = pb.start();

// Write commands
PrintWriter commands = new PrintWriter(process.getOutputStream());
commands.println("go");
commands.println("processmodel");
commands.println("show_traces -p 4 -o D:output.xml");
commands.close();

// Read from process.getInputStream(), process.waitFor(), process.exitValue()
...
```

Comment: i have not much idea of process builder

Comment: thank you so much your answer is useful for me now my code is working :)